# How to remove this skewer? A security feature?

Tags: lock, security, skewer

I have this skewer but it seems to have, what looks like some sort of security feature and I can't figure out how to remove. Can anyone identify this or have any suggestions on how to remove it?

[image: The open side I guess]
[image: Not sure how to grip this]

Comment: Can you share why you don't have the required tool?  Did you buy the bike used?

Comment: It points at a shady provenance of the bike. To say the least.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the photo you've included it looks like a [Pitlock skewer (article #P050000)](https://www.pitlock.de/en/protect/quick-release/set-sichert-hinterrad.html). If you have not noticed yet, these are used as a lock to prevent unauthorized wheel removal.

To remove these you need a special PIT-key that goes onto the part shown in the your first photo. I'm not sure how to remove the skewer without this special key, perhaps you can buy it from Pitlock or maybe someone here knows a workaround.

Comment: The seller of the bike should have the key or at least a code for making a new key

Comment: What if the seller does not have the key or code? Is it possible to obtain a PIT key from the manufacturer without a code?

Comment: That would enable thieves to just buy keys for stolen bikes.

Comment: In some countries it's not just philosophical but also legal question: knowingly buying stolen property is equal to stealing it firsthand, and missing keys are a great tip that the bike is indeed stolen.

Comment: @VladimirF obviously, but I thought that perhaps this kind of key is more akin to e.g. a tamper resistant torx screw than to an actual bike-lock key.

Comment: @ojs, looking at the PIT key this is a typical tool that I would lose during a move or cleanout of my shed, together with the label that has the code. I understand that it's often illegal to buy/sell stolen property, but I'm not sure one can assume that the bike is stolen if a key to the skewers is missing.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke and of course the natural next actions are a) sell the bike and make it the buyer's problem, b) forget that the lock existed in the first place and ask on the Internet what it could be.

Comment: If the seller can't provide a key or code for a bike they've genuinely had sitting idle in a shed until a clear-out, they should expect to get next to nothing for the bike.  Price as if stolen

Comment: Bit off-topic, but I'm not sure where this generalizing certainty comes from, I would say it's at least geographically dependent. E.g. in NL, if you sell a bike that is missing a key to a *lock that immobilizes the bike* you don't get "next to nothing" for it as long as you're open about it and show effort to prove that the bike is not stolen (e.g. providing a serial number, letting the police check if the bike is stolen, etc...) This question is about a lock that hampers quick removal of a bike part, this would have an even smaller impact on the price.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke If you have to ask, it's because you're trying really hard to ignore the concept of a lock, or why someone might lock parts to a bicycle. Just mentioning it would have avoided the whole discussion.

Comment: Alright, not sure what the added value is, but I've added the obvious.

Comment: @ojs these skewers are part of security theatre and have no real value or purpose once the bike is in a workshop setting, other than to add a little prep time. They may or may not help prevent your wheels being stolen out in the wild.

Comment: @JoeK the OP seems to disagree. I still think that the main question is whether something is yours to take if it's not locked down so hard that it's physically impossible to take it or not.

Comment: @JoeK I disagree with "security theatre". Sometimes, locking the frame to something out there can be complicated for many reasons while locking a wheel is easier. With ordinary quick release skewers, locking a wheel is completely pointless. Security features like this make locking a wheel useful (enough to make a thief grab the bike next to yours).

Answer (score 4):

I have to deal with these security skewers from time to time because people forget they are on there, lose the key, sell the bike, lend the bike to someone and don't tell them about the stupid skewer -- they are pretty irritating.

Many types you can remove without damaging (though may not be able to do back up). This type I think you will have to permanently alter to remove, either with a hacksaw, grinder or drill. It won't be very hard, just plan how you are going to do it and don't let the powertools damage the frame/paint.

[image: reddit discussion]

This reddit discusson screenshot covers a similar question.